# Is there any small laser tracker optimized for small workspaces

Tags: optics, lasers, embedded-systems, distance-measurement, metrology

A conventional laser tracker is usually large, but allows measuring up to a couple of meters away with great accuracy.

However, if we are only interested to measure a target that is only a few centimeters away (say 20cm), is there any laser tracker or device that is not very big, e.g., smaller than human's hand? Even better suitable for embedded systems applications.

Comment: perhaps a sonar

Comment: @jsotola do you know a commercial device ?